# Enumerating folders and files using Google Drive SDK V2

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am a little confused by the [v2 Google Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference).

There seems to be 2 methods to retrieve information about files and folders.

[files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) and [children.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list)

Using `files.list` I do not seem to be able to narrow my search to files in a specific folder but using `children.list` only returns very basic file information such as ID. There are no filenames.

It looks like I have to retrieve a list of children and then perform a request for each child to find out its filename which seems very inefficient.

What is the normal\correct way to enumerate folders and their contents using Google Drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative approach is to use files.list with a query expression to limit by parent.

```
q='id-of-parent' in parents
```

This will give you the same results as the child collection, but with the full metadata for each item.

Answer (score 2):

**Update** --

This can now be achieved with `files.list`. You can pass the `q` parameter with a query testing the `parents` of a file or folder.

```
q='MYFOLDERID' in parents
```

More search parameters and options and examples here: https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters

**Original answer** --

Yes, this is correct. We are looking to improve this feature, but unfortunately you are stuck with this for now - sorry.

If you are enumarating all the files and folders, a better solution might be to get a flat list, and use the `parents` array in a file to generate the hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks. I will cancel my GDrive integration plans for now until the SDK is more mature. The bandwidth required to download and cache the whole drive structure is a dealbreaker on a mobile device. If you have any say in this matter, please release a lightweight (minimal dependency) Android SDK that allows us to treat the drive as a file system. i.e enumerate files\folders, delete, upload, download etc. The current SDK is so difficult to use. I want to replace Dropbox but their SDK is way better at the moment and it lets me do what I need to do.

Answer (score 2):

+1 returning metadata (at least filename) for [children.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list)

Comment: With files.list querying there is no longer a need for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all the folders in your drive  use :

```
FileList folders=service.files().list().setQ("mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'").execute();
for(File fl: folders.getItems()){
     Log.v(TAG+" fOLDER name:",fl.getTitle());
}
```